# How do I show that an object, specifically $\partial_{\mu}V^{\nu}$, is not a rank [1, 1] tensor?

Tags: tensors

I have been asked, as an exercise, to show that the coordinate derivative of the components of a vector, $\partial_{\mu}V^{\nu}$, are not the components of a [1, 1] tensor.

I have tried to show this as follows;

> A tensor is a tensor if and only if it transforms according to the transformations rules. In the case of a [1, 1] tensor, this corresponds to $$\tilde{T^{\rho}}_{\sigma} = \frac{\partial \tilde{x^{\rho}}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial{x^{\nu}}}{\partial \tilde {x^{\sigma}}}T^{\mu}_{\nu}.$$
> Therefore, for $T^{\mu}_{\nu} = \partial_{\mu}V^{\nu}$ we have, $$ \begin{align*} \frac{\partial \tilde {x^{\rho}}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial{x^{\nu}}}{\partial \tilde x^{\sigma}}\partial_{\mu}V^{\nu} &= \frac{\partial \tilde {x^{\rho}}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial\tilde{x^{\sigma}}}V^{\nu} \\ &= \frac{\partial{\tilde x^{\rho}}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\tilde{V^{\sigma}} \\ &\ne \tilde{\partial_{\rho}}\tilde{V^\sigma} \end{align*}$$

Is this the correct way to show the result, or is there an alternative, better way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing upper and lower indices. They need to match on both sides . A better match would be $T^\nu_\mu=\frac{\partial V^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}$.

You are also doing something strange with the partial derivative. Anyway, this is how I would do it

Let $V^\nu(x^k)$ be the components of a class $C^1$ contravariant vector field. Then the transformation law for this (1,0) tensor is:

$$
\bar{V^\rho}(\bar{x}^r)=\frac{\partial \bar{x}^\rho}{\partial x^\nu}V^\nu(x^q)
$$

Lets study the partial derivatives $\partial\bar{V}^\rho/\partial \bar{x}^\sigma$ using the chain rule and the fact that $x^l=x^l(\bar{x}^\sigma)$

$$
\frac{\partial \bar{V^\rho}}{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma}=\frac{\partial^2\bar{x}^\rho}{\partial x^l\partial x^\nu}\frac{\partial{x^l}}{{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma}}V^\nu+\frac{\partial \bar{x}^\rho}{\partial x^\nu}\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma}\frac{\partial V^\nu}{\partial x^l}
$$

By now it should be quite evident that the partial derivatives ($\partial V^\nu/\partial x^l$) are not the components of a tensor since the presence of the first term on the right side is not part of the transformation rule for a rank (1,1)-tensor. The second term looks nice though!

If we could just find a way to eliminate the first term things would be awesome. This might give us some clue as how to construct a new type of derivative that is indeed tensorial.

Edit: Maybe we should also make the observation that the offending first term on the right side is due to the fact that the coordinate transformation $\bar{x}^j=\bar{x}^j(x^h)$ is not assumed to be linear. If we restrict ourselves to linear transformations the term is actually zero and the partial derivatives $\partial V^\nu/\partial x^l$ represent the components of a type (1,1) $affine$ tensor.

Comment: Oh my, my question does rather seem to be riddled with some odd manipulations. Thank you for pointing that out, and your answer! :)